# Error extending SharePoint 2010 Web Application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fba

When trying to extend an existing SharePoint 2010 web application, I get an error.
The Web App is running Claims Authentication.
I disabled NTLM Auth on the Default Zone - we want the public (default) zone to be Claims / FBA only.
We need to expand the web app to make a new zone to enable Search (requires NTLM Auth).

ERROR:
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.    at System.Number.StringToNumber
(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)     at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebSite.Lookup(Uri uri, Boolean requireHighMatchLevel, Int32& instanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProvisioningAssistant.StopSitesWithMatchingBindings(SPIisSettings settings)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionWebApplication(String webApplicationName, String applicationPoolName, SPIisSettings[] settings, Boolean adminWebApp)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSi... 8da4ec82-1802-48c3-b595-21a968db9718
06/29/2010 13:24:27.32* w3wp.exe (0x103C)                           0x1364  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...tesAsAdministrator()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSites()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ExtendWebFarmPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   8da4ec82-1802-48c3-b595-21a968db9718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use ready-made solutions for the management of FBA users, you should take a look here:

http://www.devit.eu/products/121-fba-manager-sp2010-forms-based-authentication.aspx